# Latest registrations in recent changes

Tags: mediawiki

I do not want to display the latest user registrations in the MediaWiki recent changes. Is there a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the actions by registered users and see only anonymous edits, or restrict to some namespace. What's the point?